# Modify metadata on MongoDB GridFSBucket (Java)

Tags: java, mongodb, gridfs

I am using GridFS to add files into my MongoDB database. These files have metadata attached to them. I now want to modify the metadata on one of those files. I am using **version 3.9** java driver.

I am using GridFSBucket to access the GridFS collection. However, the find() methods on GridFSBucket return instances of com.mongodb.client.gridfs.model.GridFSFile - which have no setter methods to allow me to change the metadata.

I see that com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSFile does have methods to modify the metadata - but to get instances of these objects, I would need to be using GridFS which does not seem to be recommended anymore. Certainly the documentation for the 3.9 version of GridFS relies on using GridFSBucket.

So my question is:

1. Am I correct that I should be using GridFSBucket (and not GridFS)
2. How do I then access and modify the metadata without resorting to hacking into the fs.files collection (which feels like cheating).

FWIW, here is my code:

```
String id = "5c05278530a59030cc89fc2f";)   // hex id
com.mongodb.client.gridfs.model.GridFSFile file = gridFSBucket.find( eq( "_id", new ObjectId( id ) ) ).first();
Document d = file.getMetadata(); // No corresponding setMetadata()
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter with this problem. Currently latest driver is [3.11](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.11/javadoc/) and found 3 possible actions to follow:

1. You can use [GridFSUploadOptions](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.11/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/gridfs/model/GridFSUploadOptions.html#metadata(org.bson.Document)) and upload the file you deserve. However this is only possible for initial case and probably doesn't cover what you need.
2. You can use [com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSFile setMetaData method](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.11/javadoc/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFSFile.html#setMetaData(com.mongodb.DBObject)). I'm aware this may also not you are looking for since you prefer to use new driver classes/methods.
3. You can manipulate your `bucket.files` as collection to modify metadata.

```
MongoCollection<Document> gridFSFiles = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbName").getCollection("bucketName" + ".files");
Document metadata = gridFSFiles.get("metadata", Document.class);
// update metadata and update collection
```

As far as I understand, developers of mongodb driver try to eliminate user interaction with metadata in order to automatically set those fields during upload.

I hope this answer will suffice for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify it by writing a new version, and modifying the metadata in the new version. Does this do what you need?